# How to fix data discrepancies between columns from two tables

Tags: integration

The problem:
I am working for a retail site that sells various products for cars and trucks. We want to integrate eBay and Amazon API to list our products on these stores. The problem arises when I try to send Vehicle compatibility data.

Example from our DB:

```
Product ID | Other IDs | Make  | Model
  *number* | *number*  | Ford  | F150 Crew Cab
  *number* | *number*  | Chevy | Silverado 2500/3500
  *number* | *number*  | Dodge | Ram Pickup 2500-5500 HD
```

Example from eBay Master Vehicle List DB:

```
 Make      | Model
 Ford      | F-150
 Chevrolet | Silverado 2500
 Dodge     | Ram 2500
```

As seen from the examples eBay/Amazon doesn't recognize our Models. There is no easy solution like using a "split" function to split Models into Model and Sub-model for example, because every case is different. Sometimes Model fields have Submodel as well, sometimes they have a range of Submodels (2500-5500), sometimes Model is not correct (F150 instead of F-150) etc.

**Solution:**
Changing every Model in the database to a correct Model format is not an option, because our system already uses these incorrect Models for business logic.

Writing a million exceptions in the code to handle incorrect Models is not very appealing as well.

The only solution I see is to create a new table and fill it manually with correct model names and their corresponding IDs for our products. This would be very time consuming task though.

Could anyone suggest a good solution for this problem?

Comment: How do you validate this information?

Answer (score 3):

With extensive experience consulting in the automotive sector, eBay is likely using real models as they come from OEM. You're conflating models and trims in your own system.

```
F150 Crew Cab            -- Crew cab is a trim level.
Silverado 2500/3500      -- Likely two models here.
Ram Pickup 2500-5500 HD  -- likely two models here too, with HD as a trim.
```

You need to figure out what is a model and what is a trim. Or, use a third party data provider like Chromedata which provides *styles* that often determined by model and trim. If eBay provides you a list of models, you need to map those into your local data source. Usually you'll have like 60%-direct match, 20%-inferrable with accuracy, 20%-requires human Q/A.

This is just part of how to integrate with other systems.

Looking at the new eBay guide I can give you an idea of the workload if that's not an option (which I may try first because it's probably all in a day's work).

## From the eBay motors listing:

1. This [listing of category ids needs to be loaded into a hierarchical database.](http://pages.ebay.com/sellerinformation/growing/categorychanges/motors-all.html), alternatively and better [use the api](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetCategories.html)
2. Each entry needs to be weighed with the parents. and flattened.
3. Collapse it into a full text search vector.

## Local database

1. In your own database, select all of the distinct "models" and make sure that they all have the same make.
2. Create a tsquery of the `make, model`
3. Run this against the eBay motors database above.